# smart pointers in multi-threaded envrionment

Tags: c++, multithreading, smart-pointers, reference-counting

I am new to smart pointers. However, I have a basic understanding of it. What I've observed is that it is necessary for the smart pointers to get destroyed in the reverse order of their creation or else the smart pointers may misbehave. Consider the below situation:

```
sharedPtr<abc> my_ptr(new abc); //smart pointer created. Instance counter = 1.
func1(my_ptr);                  //copy constructor in smart pointer called. Instance    counter=2
func2(my_ptr);                  //copy constructor in smart pointer called. Instance counter=3
func3(my_ptr);                  //copy constructor in smart pointer called. Instance counter=4
```

Now, isn't it necessary that `func3()` exits first followed by `func2()`, `func1()` and finally my_ptr.

**Question:** What if `my_ptr` goes out of scope first (& hence tries to delete `abc`), with `func1()`, `func2()` and `func3()` still referring to `abc` (through smart pointers) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, what you observed is wrong.

The point of smart pointer is to remove the responsibility of destroying the object. That means that the object will be delete when the reference count reach 0: **it doesn't matter which pointer is destructed first**.

In your case, this would be when `my_ptr` goes out of scope (assuming you don't make and keep a copy in one your `func()`.

This is what the reference counter should be:

```
{
sharedPtr<abc> my_ptr(new abc); //smart pointer created. Ref counter = 1.
func1(my_ptr);                  // Ref counter=2 while in func1
// Ref count is 1 again.
func2(my_ptr);                  // Ref counter=2 while in func2
// Ref count is 1 again.
func3(my_ptr);                  // Ref counter=2 while in func3
// Ref count is 1 again.
} // my_ptr goes out of scope, ref count reach 0, and abc is deleted.
```

Comment: I see your point. However, this is my problem:
I want to create an event object on heap and pass this event (pass by pointer) to observer classes which in turn store the event in their respective vector<event*> for processing it at a later time. Question: How to ensure that all observers have processed the event before someone tries to delete it? Who should delete the event that was created on heap ? I don't want to COPY events in vecotr<>, instead I just want to store a pointer to the event in the vecotr<>.

Comment: Instead of having a `vector<event *>` go for a `vector<shared_ptr<event>>`. Each observer will keep the `shared_ptr` as long as it needs (I suppose until the event gets processed), and will remove it from the vector when it no longer need a reference to the event. The event will be *automatically* deleted when the last observer release the pointer (ie, removes it from its vector).

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to use. However, I am using a custom shared_ptr class instead of a standard library one.
(I am doing so, just to understand the concept).
Here's the issue:
    void publishEvent()
    {
    sharedPtr<event> start_ev(new start);  //create an event- start on heap. start_ev - ref counter = 1
    notifyObservers(start_ev);   //All observers save the event in vector<sharedPtr<event>>
    }//oops!!! start_ev deletes the event start .. 
Is this to do with a wrongly implemented custom sharedPtr ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes this is likely due to an error in you `sharedPtr` implementation. I would suggest playing with `std::shared_ptr` first, making sure you understand how to *use* them. Then, and only then I think you should try implementing your own, to learn how they *work* internally.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your custom `sharedPtr`, but for the standard [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) it works like (from the linked reference):

> The object is destroyed and its memory deallocated when either of the following happens:
>
> - the last remaining shared_ptr owning the object is destroyed.
> - the last remaining shared_ptr owning the object is assigned another pointer via operator=() or reset().

So for `std::shared_ptr` you can pass it around or make as many copies as you want, the order of destruction of those copies will not matter.

Answer (score 1):

> What I've observed is that it is necessary for the smart pointers to get destroyed in the reverse order of their creation

Well, the sole reason for existence of shared smart pointers is that one should not care when they get destroyed. When the last shared pointer gets destroyed it destroys the object, as in "the last person to leave turns the light off."